# Thread safe data management in Android to keep UI thread free

Tags: java, android, multithreading

To keep the UI unblocked Android does not recommend doing a lot of calculations on the UI thread. Is there a way then to be able to keep data objects in memory without causing contention, i.e. no thread safety issues. Lets say if I have a singleton data manager holding a cached copy of the data would that make it thread safe? or do I need to manually make the data manager class do the classic style locks and synchronisations to deal with the concurrent modifications. Are there alternative ways?

Comment: You have the same potential problems with multi-threading as anywhere else.

Comment: yes but Android being an operating system so wide in use and with so many developers, perhaps there is a better way to things other than the plain vanilla approach.

Answer (score 1):

There are many `Thread-safe` data structures to work with, which assumes a **lot** of work you won't then need to implement.

More info about them [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/collections.html). Even more info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) (recommended).